# My cron job is giving different result as compared to the python script running manually

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I have written the code to fetch data from opensearch in python script.
The last record printed through the python script is:
Connection done `2023-08-16 04:49:26.896033`
Last input time of the retrieved records: `2023-07-20T12:31:41`

But when I schedule the python script to run as cron job then the output of the last record shows the timestamp as :

```
2023-08-16T10:00:01+0000 - Running cron job...
Connection done
```

Last input time of the retrieved records: `2023-07-20T18:01:59`

There is a mismatch in data. I cannot provide the code for the python script. But I have scheduled the cron job to run every hour like this:

```
0 * * * *  /usr/bin/env bash -c 'echo "$(date -u +\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%S\%z) - Running cron job..." >> /home/opc/output.log && /usr/bin/python3 /home/opc/path/to/script/python.py >> /home/opc/output.log 2>&1'.
```

If I run the script;

```
/usr/bin/env bash -c 'echo "$(date -u +\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%S\%z) - Running cron job..." >> /home/opc/output.log && /usr/bin/python3 /home/opc/path/to/script/python.py >> /home/opc/output.log 2>&1'
```

then the data printed is correctly but not as cron job.

Have I scheduled the cron job incorrectly?
Can anyone help me.

I want the cron job to provide the exact data as the python script.

Comment: Hard to tell without the code. Also, if you run the scripts in both ways again, do you still have the same result ? Could it be that a new record got in in between the two executions ?

Comment: @Itération122442 Yes both are giving different results. No No the data is static. Is the cron job timed correctly? Is there an issue with time zones.